# Migrating from Angular 1.2.14 to 1.4.2 breaks whole application

Tags: angularjs, migrate

I have angular App defined with following:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute','infinite-scroll','geolocation', 'ngAnimate', 'ngTouch','ui.filters', 'AxelSoft','angularLazyImg','wu.masonry','ui.bootstrap','ngSanitize']);
```

Until now I was using AngularJS version **1.2.14**. Now I need to use AngularJS form validations and in order to do that, I have decided to migrate to Angular's latest stable version **1.4.2**.

When I have changed the angular version, things got broke and console throws

*Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]* with following stack trace :

**Error: $injector:modulerr
Module Error**

```
Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
    at http://localhost:8000/static/mobile/js/angularApp/app.js:6:37
    at Object.e [as invoke] (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular.min.js:39:156)
    at d (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular.min.js:37:328)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular.min.js:37:452
    at m (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular.min.js:7:322)
    at g (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular.min.js:37:229)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular.min.js:37:398
    at m (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular.min.js:7:322)
    at g (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular.min.js:37:229)
    at eb (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular.min.js:40:503
```

I have tried reading and understanding angularJS official migration guide but I coudn't able to figure out what's in it for me as I haven't used $animate in my code(It $animate and $touch are injected only for another plugin to work i.e. sliders and also I have used 'ngROute anywhere')

Does anyone have idea what should be done here as I have no idea about where do I start :)

Comment: What do you have on line 6? in your app.js

Comment: Your dependencies aren't compatible with the new version of angular you are using. Go to each 3rd party site and then download the appropriate version for use with angular 1.4.2 or change your bower configuration accordingly.

Comment: Hello Babajide, Here is the code for line 5-6 in which I am using HTTP interceptors to intercept HTTP requests and show loader:
----------------------
myApp.config(function ($httpProvider) {

  $httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push('myHttpInterceptor');//line 6

Answer (score 0):

So here is what was needed to be done to migrate my angular Application.

1. Migrate ngRoute and ngAnimate with the same version of angular
2. Remove HTTP interceptors which was in 1.2 and change them to the style of angular 1.4

In my case, removing $httpProvider and migration ngAnimate and ngRoute had solved my problem.